# How to update the only changed fields in Firestore?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

In the `users` collection in Firestore, I have all users' `uid` as documents, inside each user document I am storing user preferences.

For example, here's a sample of user preferences I am saving in a specific user document:

```json
{
  "preferences": {
    "settings": {
      "themeColorMode": "light-mode",
      "debugMode": false
    },
    "filterChips": {
      "pathName": {
        "filterChipsPreferences": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

I want to update user document with the data sent in the body of an API

I want that API to be compatible in a way such that

- I should be able to add another root node other than preferences
- I should be able to customize and add new nodes in `preferences.settings` & `preferences.filterChips`
- I should be able to update a specific node - examples: `preferences.settings.themeColorMode`& `preferences.filterChips.filterChipsPreferences`

For example, in the request body I am sending this info:

```json
{
  "preferences": {
    "settings": {
      "themeColorMode": "dark-mode",
      "isSoundNotificationOn": false,
      "isAppListeningToStream": true
    },
    "filterChips": {
      "pathName": {
        "filterChipsPreferences": false
      },
      "FirstUsedSearch": "23/12/2021"
    },
    "columnDefs": {
      "pathName": {
        "ColumnDefsPreferences": true
      }
  },
  },
  "search": {
      "savedSearches":["searchName"]
    }
}
```

---

I am expecting this result to be saved in the user's document

```json
{
  "preferences": {
    "settings": {
      "themeColorMode": "dark-mode",
      "isSoundNotificationOn": false,
      "isAppListeningToStream": true,
      "debugMode": false
    },
    "filterChips": {
      "pathName": {
        "filterChipsPreferences": false
      },
      "FirstUsedSearch": "23/12/2021"
    },
    "columnDefs": {
      "pathName": {
        "ColumnDefsPreferences": true
      }
  },
  "search": {
      "savedSearches":["searchName"]
    }
  }
}
```

How could I approach that?

Comment: Do you really want to build your own API that will receive the payload and then connect to Firestore? Or you are ready/OK to use the standard JavaScript SDK?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec it has to be an API that receives the payload from the frontend users and gives it to the server which will connect to Firestore to implement the points mentioned above, do you think that's possible?

Comment: Sure it is possible. But which kind of server will connect to Firestore? What language can you use on this server? It should be possible to use, on this server, one of the server libraries offered by the Admin SDK.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I am using typescript as a language, and yes I am using the Firebase Admin SDK

Comment: Ok, I'll write an anwser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the Node.js Admin SDK on the server that calls Firestore, it is actually quite straightforward: you need to use the [`update()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#update) method of the `DocumentReference`.

> The `update()` method accepts either an object with field paths encoded
> as keys and field values encoded as values, or a variable number of
> arguments that alternate between field paths and field values.

More precisely:

```
// 1/ Define your DocumentReference
const userId  = ...;
const docRef = admin.firestore().doc(`users/${userId}`);

// 2/ Get the desired elements from the payload received by your API and use them to build the object to pass to the update method

// For example

const updateObj = {
    preferences.settings.debugMode: false,
    preferences.settings.themeColorMode: "myColor",
    preferences.filterChips.filterChipsPreferences: "myPref",
    aNewRootNode: {
       foo: 'bar',
       bar: 'foo'
    }
}

await docRef.update(updateObj);
```

---

More info on how to update fields in nested objects can be found in the [doc of the JS SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-8_10).